# iterating array of objects which is present inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, redux

children.BallAdequacy is an array of objects.Inside that playerRank is an array of objects.
From each playerRank array I need to display Ball and playerHeight value seprately in console.
I used map and filter methods but still I am not able to print the ball and playerHeight for each object.
 Can you tell me how to fix it.
Providing my code snippet and data below

example for each object  it should print **222--->HEIGHT,ww22w22--->HEIGHT, etc**

```js
let children = {
  BallAdequacy: [{
      "flight": "dd",

      "specialty": "ff",

      "playerRank": [{
          "Ball": "222",
          "playerHeight": "HEIGHT"
        },
        {
          "Ball": "ddeeeew",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        },
      ],
      "hospitalPrivilege": []
    },
    {
      "flight": "kkk",
      "specialty": "ff",

      "playerRank": [{
          "Ball": "kfkf",
          "playerHeight": "HEIGHT"
        },
        {
          "Ball": "All",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        }
      ],
      "hospitalPrivilege": []
    }
  ]
};


children.BallAdequacy.map(status => {
  console.log("status.playerRank--->", status.playerRank);
  status.playerRank.filter(game => {
    //console.log("game.playerHeight--->", game.playerHeight);
    if (game.playerHeight === 'HEIGHT') {
      console.log("after if --->", game);
      console.log("after if --->", game.Ball);

    }
    // (game.playerHeight === 'HEIGHT')
    //console.log("outsidei f--->", game);
  });
  console.log("after filter status.playerRank--->", status.playerRank);
  //BallList = getBalls(status.playerRank);
});
```

Comment: tamil. I have tidied and created snippet. Could you add desired output format.

Comment: look like the code works. You expect a different output or just met some errors? Like asynchronous data from redux?

Comment: @Bibberty updated my question with correct output...thanks for your help...can you post  the answer

Comment: @bird updated my question with correct output...thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Follow the definition of `map()` and `filter()`

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
>
> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Both methods return a new array, It must clone a new object, but you don't need that. All you need is just `console.log` something and didn't change the data. You should use `forEach` instead. And remove some unnecessary console.

```js
let children = {
  BallAdequacy: [{
      "flight": "dd",

      "specialty": "ff",

      "playerRank": [{
          "Ball": "222",
          "playerHeight": "HEIGHT"
        },
        {
          "Ball": "ww22w22",
          "playerHeight": "HEIGHT"
        },

        {
          "Ball": "wwwww",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        },
        {
          "Ball": "ddeeeew",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        },

        ,
        {
          "Ball": "All",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        }
      ],
      "hospitalPrivilege": []
    },
    {
      "flight": "kkk",
      "specialty": "ff",

      "playerRank": [{
          "Ball": "kfkf",
          "playerHeight": "HEIGHT"
        },

        {
          "Ball": "iioioo",
          "playerHeight": "HEIGHT"
        },
        {
          "Ball": "24jk",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        },


        {
          "Ball": "All",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        }
      ],
      "hospitalPrivilege": []
    }
  ]
};





children.BallAdequacy.forEach(status => {
  status.playerRank.forEach(game => {
    if (game.playerHeight === 'HEIGHT') {
      console.log(`${game.Ball} ---> ${game.playerHeight}`);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? Does this work?

```js
let children = {
  BallAdequacy: [{
      "flight": "dd",

      "specialty": "ff",

      "playerRank": [{
          "Ball": "222",
          "playerHeight": "HEIGHT"
        },
        {
          "Ball": "ww22w22",
          "playerHeight": "HEIGHT"
        },

        {
          "Ball": "wwwww",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        },
        {
          "Ball": "ddeeeew",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        },
        {
          "Ball": "All",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        }
      ],
      "hospitalPrivilege": []
    },
    {
      "flight": "kkk",
      "specialty": "ff",

      "playerRank": [{
          "Ball": "kfkf",
          "playerHeight": "HEIGHT"
        },

        {
          "Ball": "iioioo",
          "playerHeight": "HEIGHT"
        },
        {
          "Ball": "24jk",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        },


        {
          "Ball": "All",
          "playerHeight": "NON-HEIGHT"
        }
      ],
      "hospitalPrivilege": []
    }
  ]
};

let output = children.BallAdequacy.map(s => s.playerRank.map((a) => `${a.Ball}-->${a.playerHeight}`).join());

output.forEach(c => console.log(c));
```